# Arguments too long for check_output? Fail with error 127

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, command-line-arguments

I need to call an executable from my Python script and recover its output. So I am doing this:

```
command = executable + ' -a something ' + variable + ' -b somethingElse'
output = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(command),shell=True)
```

And when I execute this, I obtain an error 127. The problem might be linked to the size of the arguments: the final string that gets executed is more than 1300 characters long. But the strange thing is that if I copy-paste that string into a shell and execute it, then it works perfectly. Is there a limit in Python that I am not aware of? I think I could design other solutions but (a) I would prefer this one and (b) I am curious about this issue.

Comment: What does `executable` contain - just a program name or a full path?

Comment: why splitting a string instead of passing the arguments as a `list` directly?

Comment: @Błotosmętek It contains the full (absolute) path to the executable

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No particular reason... It's just the approach I followed in all other cases (where this method works perfectly fine)

Comment: instead of editing your question with "solved", you should [edit] your question with the proper code and answer your own question. That would be interesting. I knew that `shell=True` is bad and should be avoided, but I had no idea it could affect the size of the command line. Do that you'll get some upvotes.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Done, thanks. I did not know it either, but now it works, so I guess that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Removing `shell=True` (which wasn't needed anyway) solved the argument length problem.

Lesson learned: don't use `shell=True` unless you can't do anything else (and even in that case, there's probably a better solution)